# Can we uproot a Wheezewort only once?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

It seems, that if we uproot a [Wheezewort](http://oxygennotincluded.gamepedia.com/Wheezewort_Seed) from one Flower Vase (to plant it into another) it get destroyed/used/disappear.

Is this 'by design'?

How can I transport such a Wheezewort from one place to another?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should submit a bug report on the [bug tracker](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/klei-bug-tracker/oni-alpha/) since it is not the intended behavior.
I tried to do this on 3 different saves and had no problem relocating my chilly Wheezewort.

Comment: Are you sure that you tried to relocate from one Flower Vase to another Flower Vase (not from the original place in a ice biom to the first Flower Vase)?